# manage create method of django when there are lots of fields

Tags: python, django, design-patterns

I am working on project where I have taken django in backend. I have a model call profile which is related to the user. A profile model has more than 10 fields and when trying to update the user profile, my code for updating all those fields would be something like this

```
class UpdateProfile(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        input = types.ProfileInput(required=True)

    success = graphene.Boolean()
    errors = graphene.List(graphene.String)
    profile = graphene.Field(schema.ProfileNode)

    @staticmethod
    def mutate(self, info, **args):
        is_authenticated = info.context.user.is_authenticated
        data = args.get('input')
        if not is_authenticated:
            errors = ['unauthenticated']
            return UpdateProfile(success=False, errors=errors)
        else:
            profile = Profile.objects.get(user=info.context.user)
            profile = models.Profile.objects.get(profile=profile)
            profile.career = data.get('career', None)
            profile.payment_type = data.get('payment_type', None)
            profile.expected_salary = data.get('expected_salary', None)
            profile.full_name = data.get('full_name', None)
            profile.age = data.get('age', None)
            profile.city = data.get('city', None)
            profile.address = data.get('address', None)
            profile.name_of_company = data.get('name_of_company', None)
            profile.job_title = data.get('job_title', None)
            profile.zip_code = data.get('zip_code', None)
            profile.slogan = data.get('slogan', None)
            profile.bio = data.get('bio', None)
            profile.website = data.get('website', None)
            profile.github = data.get('github', None)
            profile.linkedin = data.get('linkedin', None)
            profile.twitter = data.get('twitter', None)
            profile.facebook = data.get('facebook', None)
            profile.image=info.context.FILES.get(data.get('image', None))
            profile.save()
            return UpdateProfile(profile=profile, success=True, errors=None)
```

so my question is, suppose, if there are even more than 20, 30 fields, how would you design your code on updating those fields? (considering only views part)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a kwargs(means dictionary) for whatever values you are getting  from frontend and then you can unpack those values. Unpacking concept you can go though if you are not aware.

Lets suppose kwargs is your dictionary and you want to update only career and payment_type.

```
kwargs = {}

kwargs['carrer'] = data.get('career', None)
kwargs['payment_type'] = data.get('payment_type', None)

Profile.objects.filter(user=info.context.user).update(**kwargs)
```